# Creating TFS branches where they do not already exist

Tags: tfs, version-control, branching-and-merging, tfvc

I have On premise TFS2017 with Update 1 (15.112.26307.0).

Within my Project collection, I have a project that we shall call Project1; it is represented in source control as "$/Project1". This project has no branches, the solution file is in the root ("$/Project1/Project1.sln") and all of the source is in folders off of the root (e.g. "$/Project1/Application1", "$/Project1/Library1", "$/Project1/Library2"). As you will expect, there are references between the various projects and all of the projects have history.

I want to introduce branches to the project and need to move all of the existing development into a new folder off of the root so that I can then branch from this folder. In Source Control Explorer, I have created a new folder called "master" ("$/Project1/master") that will be the main branch from which other development branches will be created.

How do I now move the existing solution files into that folder in such a way as to not lose any of the history and also maintain the existing relationships between the components?

I have tried selecting the other folders in the root of the project ("$/Project1/Project1.sln", "$/Project1/Application1", "$/Project1/Library1", "$/Project1/Library2") and going for the move command, but it is greyed out. I have also read elsewhere that if I move the folders this way it is effectively a delete and then a new file and that I will lose all history.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to create your folder and check-in that pending change.
Then you can convert the folder to a branch in source control explorer, by right clicking the folder.

[image]

After you converted you folder to a branch, **you have to Get Latest Version, so that you have the code locally on your machine. This will enable the Move command on context menu.**

Answer (score 0):

***Move command disabled in source control.***

> This is usually because **you don't have the parent folder mapped
>   locally.**
>
> Also, it can occur if the parent folder is mapped to a different
>   location so as the structure of local mapping does not match the
>   structure of server folders.

***About the moved file/folder history in TFS***

There isn’t a way to keep the folder history.

The copy (Branch) will lost the folder history, **but the individual file history is actually not lost.** It is hidden under the little "expand me" arrow at the far left on a file history line. Expand it on the oldest history entry for a file, or anywhere you see it, and you will see history of that individual file also from an old location that no longer exists.

Details please reference this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28990323/moving-files-lose-history-in-tfs-2013