# Is it possible to move folders from one set of TFS branches into another and preserve pending changes?

Tags: tfs, tfvc

At present, our TFS (TFVC, *not* git) project contains a folder that hosts the entirety of our product. This folder contains three branches (Dev, Main and Release) each of which in turn contains *many* different sub projects. We are attempting to restructure so that distinct components are contained within their own branching structure.

Question: Is it possible to move a folder that is contained under a branch (not the branch itself), along with its corresponding folder in the other branches into a *new* TFS project while maintaining the relationship and status of any unmerged changesets?

Here is a diagram of our desired end result:

[image: target structure]

We want to move each of the "Project 1" *folders* (left side) into their own branching structure (right side), but we need any unmerged changesets to "come along". That is to say that if we attempt to Merge from Dev to Main in the new structure we are presented with a list of the (pertinent) changesets that were not merged in the old structure.

Is this possible? If so, **what series of `tf`/tfvc commands** would we need to pull this off? I've gone deep into google, but came up short--either because I don't know how to describe this in a search friendly way, or its simply impossible.

What I've tried:

- Direct Move/Rename each of the folders into the new project (*pre-creating* each of the target Dev/Main/Release branches)

  - The unmerged changesets were lost.
  - All I get is a single "move/rename" changeset that appears in the unmerged list for the new branches. Merging *that* causes everything in the target branch to be overwritten (ie. release branch's files are now the same as dev).
  - On the +side, pending shelvesets "auto-follow" when unshelved
- Branch each *folder*, into the new structure (this time without pre-creating the target branch folders)

  - This created three branches that weren't related to each other.
  - I was able to solve that by doing a baseless merge between them (`tf merge /baseless /recursive`) and taking target branch files when conflicted; followed by re-parenting the branches. (As explained [here](https://alistairbmackay.wordpress.com/2014/01/15/tfs-reparenting-a-branch/))
  - Unlike the above, the files themselves ended up correct (nothing was overwritten).
  - The unmerged changesets were lost.
  - Shelvesets get unshelved to the *original* location

If it matters, we are willing to lose overall history if that's the only way to solve this. Preferably we'd keep it, even if it meant storing a 'deprecated' copy of the original somewhere. I'm not so concerned about shelvesets "following" their source either... we only have two that would be impacted and we can handle those manually if needed. We are using on-prem TFS 2018.

Edit: in response to an answer that was posted and then deleted:

I'm not looking to move the branches, but to **extract folders** deep inside them into their own corresponding branch structure without losing pending changes. I only show two levels above, but in reality they are a lot deeper. I am able to `tf rename` an entire branch in a sandbox and get expected results... but renaming branches is not what I'm trying to do, and moving the folders gives unexpected results.

Comment: This is most likely a Git problem, not a TFS problem.  If you can figure out how to get what you want through a Git operation, the TFS problem should solve itself.

Comment: We don't use Git. We use TFS+TFVC, hence the tags. To your point that becomes a TFVC problem and finding the correct TFVC operation/`tf` commands which is what we're seeking

Comment: Tags are nice for categorizing questions, but I seldom look at them when reading posts.  You might mention that in the body of your question.  For what it's worth, I don't know of *anyone else* that uses TFVC; the whole ecosystem has coalesced around Git.

Comment: I *wish* we were on Git, but I don't see it happening any time in the near future unfortunately.  I forgot that Git+TFS was a thing which is why I assumed it was obvious from the post, will add to the body though

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 For your reference: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28990323/moving-files-lose-history-in-tfs-2013)

Comment: @Kousic thanks I've seen that and it's not quite what I'm after. rename/move don't seem to help here when trying to move into a new branch, especially three at once. It then creates an operation that itself wants to be merged

Comment: (https://www.fillanypdf.com/Download/Shared/9c3cfe9d-65be-4f42-aca9-c14957eaa7cc/TFS%20Branching%20Guidance.pdf)

Comment: Maybe a little bit late to the game. But if loosing history is okay, why isn't a simple copy of the folders a option? The pending changes part, could be solved with get latest to another folder first, move stuff, check in. Then copy everything from original folder, all files that are different will then be pending changes in the new folder. Am I missing something obvious with this approach? 

Comment: @Mötz it creates a new changeset that contains all files in it which then sits in the pending merge list once you commit. But other than that, your strategy doesn't work: we need to know what those pending changes are. It's not just a single file that may be different, and we need to be able to selectively merge up. There's pending changes that need to go from Dev to main and others from main to release to boot. I've yet to come up with a strategy. There *may* be a way turning it into 5 branches (2 unrelated) and slowly widdle that down with a series of baseless merges but untested and complex

Comment: I overlooked the unmerged changesets between the branches requirement, sorry about that. What about expanding/branching all your branches 3 times, 1 for each project. That would leave you with a Dev, Main and Release set for each project. Now you could remove the unneeded project folders per set, so you are left with Dev[Project-1], Main[Project-1], Release[Project-1], Dev[Project-2], Main[Project-2], Release[Project-2], Dev[Project-3], Main[Project-3], Release[Project-3]

Comment: Never mind. I'm beginning to see where the issue is. If my idea were to succeed, we would have to branch from the first changeset, "replay" all changesets from the source branch (keep the original name as the comment for the check-in), for this to work.

Comment: I had a similar thought. Branch each folder, do all new work in  New-Dev. When ready Merge changes from old-Dev to old-main And new-main (baseless). Once complete drop old-Dev,  baseless merge and reparent. Rinse repeat for main->release. Problem is it would still be a ton of baseless merging in between (and would only work if nothing needs to merge from new-Dev to new-main) and most likely hard to track. I think it *could* work, though not sure I have the specifics nailed down and I'd like to avoid something so complex if at all possible

Comment: Also something to note is that the drive behind all of this is that we want to create a fourth "alpha" branch for at least one of the projects to act as a quasi-feature branch. Unfortunately we don't feature branch (we can't given the state of things currently). This would be a major push in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you can achieve what you are wanting by having merge relationships from both the new Dev, Main, Release branches *and* the old project folders.  I think you can do a variation of the second "route" you tried above.

1. Branch the **old** Release > Project[x] folder into the **new** Project[x] > Release branch
2. Branch the **new** Project[x] > Release Branch into the **new** Project[x] > Main branch
3. Merge (baseless) the **old** Main > Project[x] folder (specifying the changeset that 
    the **old** Release was branched from) into the **new** Project[x] > Main branch
4. Branch the **new** Project[x] > Main Branch into the **new** Project[x] > Dev branch
5. Merge (baseless) the **old** Dev > Project[x] folder (specifying the changeset that 
   **old** Main was branched from) into the **new** Project[x] > Dev branch
6. Repeat for the other Projects

The goal is to create the new branch merge relationships (by branching [new] Release to [New] Main and then [New] Main to [New] Dev.  At this point the merge relationship has been established and all branches are in the same state.  Then we baseless merge the [old] to the [new] for main and Dev.  For Main we want to dot he baseless merge on the state where Main and Release are the same (in the old).  For Dev we want to do the baseless merge on the state where Dev and Main are the same (in the old).  Then additional merges may occur from [old] to [new] and these should be detected as merge-able changes from [new] to [new] similar to how they are in [old] to [old]

You will loose the shelve sets (but can always unshelve in the old location, checkin, and merge to the new) but history should be retained as long as the old project isn't destroyed.

Comment: This looks good and I'm going to give it a try. Unfortunately (if it works) you missed out on the 350 point bounty I had going on the question which expired the other day.  Our branches were Branched starting with Main. Main was branched to Dev and then Main was branched to Release (the current relationship is that Main is the parent of both, but when we merge we merge Dev->Main->Release). With that in mind, are you able to update the answer assuming it would make a difference?

Comment: Yeah I sure can, but a follow up question I would ask is where do you have pending merge changes?  I was assuming Main > Release and Dev > Main.  But do you also have Main > Dev pending changes as well?

Comment: No just dev->main and main->release

Comment: ok I updated the answer, but thinking about it, the initial way should work (maybe even better) since release is in this case the "most stable".  But let me know how it works and I can make updates accordingly.

Comment: Thanks. It's too late in the day (for me) to start trying anything, but I will give it a go tomorrow morning. I'll keep you posted

Comment: It doesn't work but I think I see how its *supposed* to. First, when I get conflicts on the baseless I assume I should take source version (not target)? 2. It appears that I would *then* need to merge ALL changesets (from the start) for each Old->New branch to get them to the desired state (since the changes aren't yet in [New])? 3.The baseless merge leaves a *new* unmerged changeset in [New]; I should be able to remove that with `/discard`, right? 4. If there's any *unmerged* Old Main->Old Release it doesn't show up in any of the pending lists (except old main->old release of course) [Cont'd]

Comment: 5. As I'm not concerned with history (much) could I pick an arbitrary later dated changeset as the baseless source? (ex. the last time we merged to Release)? This seems like it'd give me a smaller list to manually maintain. 6. Should my original branch be using latest source or should I specify a changeset? 7. Since it looks like I'll have to manually merge each set, could I just create ONE branch based off the originals (ex. Dev) baseless merge THAT using a later changeset and just re-branch from there (for new main/release) and manually merge the outstanding changesets (sitting in DEV)?

Comment: 2. yes this is also correct.  I can make it more clear in my answer, but also why I mentioned it may be easier to start with Release rather than Main (since all changes have happened in Main and Dev).  Basically you want to have a merge relationship between [New]Dev > Main > Release where they are all in the exact same state (code is the same).  When you Baseless merge from old to new you are establishing a merge relationship between old and new, but you want to choose the changeset where the two connected branches were in the same state.  Then when you merge additional changes from old [cont]

Comment: **I rolled back my answer to reflect using the release branch as your start**
4.  When you do the baseless merge of [old] main to [new] you are targeting the changeset that has main be in the same state as Release.  That way when you merge any other changeset beyond that from [old] main to [new] main it will be recognized as a mergable update to release.
5. you can, or you can merge multiple changesets at once from [old] to [new] but keep in mind that this will create a new changeset in the [new] branch and unless targeting specific files cant be seperated when merging from [new] to [new]

Comment: 7.  this process works best buy starting with the most stable branch (or has the least changes relatively) and then moving down the flow of merge relationships to the branch with the most changes.  Plus if you started with Dev you would be creating a merge relationship between Dev > Main and Dev> Release but not Main > Release

Comment: Thank you for your help. Got it working. I ended up doing a baseless merge using the last merged changeset. It made my "to be merged" list a hell of a lot shorter and I was able to combine some of those in groups. Lost some history by doing that but were not too concerned (well keep an archival copy around). I still have a bunch of smaller projects to do that I'll most likely use the original branch changeset but this was the big one